# prove Inequalities for integrals

Tags: integration, inequality

prove

$\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{1}{3}\leq \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2+\sin(x)}dx \leq \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}$

I got to the point where  $\frac{1}{3} \leq f(x) \leq 1$,
so  $\frac{\pi}{6} \leq \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}f(x)dx \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and where do I go from here , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper bound is easy:$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\mathrm{d}x\leq \int_2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos x)\mathrm{d}x=\pi/4+1/2.$$

For the lower bound, $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1+\cos x}{2+\sin x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{2+\sin x}\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{2+\sin x}\mathrm{d}x.$$ The first term on the right hand side is $\geq \pi/6$. The second term $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{2+\sin x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2+t}\mathrm{d}t=\ln 3-\ln 2 \geq 1/3.$$

Comment: Why is it 1/2(1+cos(x))?

Comment: $1/(2+\sin x)\leq 1/2.$